# unrecognized arguments: –html

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create an application using Azure App service.

However, it shows the above error: **unrecognized arguments: –html**

The command that I use is az webapp up --location AustraliaEast --name learmingapp –html.

Comment: I think it should be `--html`, @Jennie. [az webapp up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use the command to update and display my website with a new header.
> However, it shows the above error: unrecognized arguments: –html

***To resolve the above issue , In your script the argument that you are using `-html`instead of that need to use `--html`*** as suggested by @[***Ash***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9164015/ash) as well,Posting it as an answer to help other community members for similar issue.

***For example:-*** `az webapp up --location AustraliaEast --name learmingapp --html`

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [**`MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up) .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me to resolve this issue.

It is correct.

az webapp up --location AustraliaEast --name learmingapp --html

Comment: Maybe could explain what's the code at the last line for